# msbuild - sed command error - how to include single quote and double quote

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, sed, msbuild

I have a `GNU makefile` that I'm translating to `MSBuild`.

There is a command containing `sed` that won't run in `MSBuild` because it contains a `'` (single quote) that is interfering with the single quote that's supposed to close the `Command` attribute of `Exec` task:

```
<Target Name="prebuild_cat">
    <Exec
        EchoOff="true"
        StandardOutputImportance="low"
        StandardErrorImportance="low"
        IgnoreExitCode="true"
        ConsoleToMSBuild="true" 
        Command=' $(GnuSed) 's/^Q(.*)/"&"/'    
    '>
    </Exec>
</Target>
```

When I run this, Visual Studio says

> error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. 's' is an unexpected token. Expecting white space. Line 244, position 25.

When I replace `'` with `&apos;` and `"` with `&quot;`

```
<Target Name="prebuild_cat">
    <Exec
        EchoOff="true"
        StandardOutputImportance="low"
        StandardErrorImportance="low"
        IgnoreExitCode="true"
        ConsoleToMSBuild="true" 
        Command=' $(GnuSed) &apos;s/^Q(.*)/&quot;&&quot;/&apos;    
    '>
    </Exec>
</Target>
```

> error MSB4025: The project file could not be loaded. An error occurred while parsing EntityName.

Comment: Any update for this issue? Have you resolved this issue? If not, please let me know the latest status for this issue.

Comment: @Leo-MSFT I chose an answer: my issue was that I forgot to replace `&` with `&amp;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> msbuild - sed command error - how to include single quote and double quote

According to the document [MSBuild Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters):

> MSBuild reserves some characters for special use in specific contexts. You only have to escape such characters if you want to use them literally in the context in which they are reserved.

**To escape a special character, use the syntax %xx, where xx represents the ASCII hexadecimal value of the character.**

In this case, the single quote is ASCII character 39, which is 27 in hex. And the value for & is 26, so the correct escape sequence is:

```
'$(GnuSed) %27s/^Q(.*)/"%26"/%27'
```

Below is my test sample, you can check if it works for you:

```
  <Target Name="prebuild_cat" AfterTargets="Build">
    <Message Text='$(GnuSed) %27s/^Q(.*)/"%26"/%27' Importance='high' />
  </Target>
```

The result in output windows:

```
1>prebuild_cat:
1>   's/^Q(.*)/"&"/'
1>
1>Build succeeded.
```