# msbuild - Why do I get error MSB4025 when using output redirection in my VS NMake Build Command Line?

Tags: xml, visual-studio, msbuild, nmake, output-redirect

I use a Visual Studio makefile project and have individual build commands in the NMakeBuildCommandLine property of the vcxproj file. 
When one of these commands uses output redirection like this:

```
echo "unwanted output"  >nul 2>&1
```

I get a build error when calling msbuild:

`all.vcxproj(53,30): error MSB4025:`  
`The project file could not be loaded. An error occurred while parsing EntityName. Line 53, position 33.` 
or 
`Die Projektdatei konnte nicht geladen werden. Beim Analysieren von 'EntityName' ist ein Fehler aufgetreten. Zeile 53, Position 33.`

Why?

I found the solution by myself and want to provide it here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This error can only happen, if you directly edit the `NMakeBuildCommandLine` within the vcxproj file. 
You can get the same error with other command properties too.

The reason is, that `>` and `&` are invalid special characters. 
As stated in the [MSBuild help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters), special characters need to be escaped.  
However in this help `>` and `&` are not listed, although they are invalid in XML elements and a vcxproj is xml.

The MSBuild help says

> To escape a special character, use the syntax %<xx>, where <xx> represents the ASCII hexadecimal value of the character.

which means to replace

```
echo "unwanted output"  >nul 2>&1
```

with

```
echo "unwanted output"  %3enul 2%3e%261
```

By try I found out, that the following variants do also work:

```
echo "unwanted output"  &#62;nul 2&#62;&#38;1
echo "unwanted output"  &gt;nul 2&gt;&amp;1
```

Interestingly, only the last 2 variants are afterwards displayed correctly in the project properties > NMake > Build Command Line as `>nul 2>&1`. 
When editing the project properties > NMake > Build Command Line directly, and you enter `>nul 2>&1`, VS writes `&gt;nul 2&gt;&amp;1` to the vcxproj.

And since the last variant is more readable than the hexadecimal syntax, I would prefer this too.

I tested with Visual Studio 17.2.5.

---

*There was also a similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46644386/16049096), but it does neither mention the character `>` (which is used for output redirection but not contained in the [MSBuild help](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters)) nor does it mention NMakeBuildCommandLine (that's the problem I was coming from). 
 So I decided to make this new question & answer to help others with a similar problem.*